# Feeding Time at the Zoo - It's Common Sense!

Tags: logical-deduction

Azeez the Assistant Zookeeper shook his head - "I'll never remember this"

"Nonsense!" snorted Jeff.  "It's common sense... no two animals eat exactly the same meals and  for each meal just think of their names - any given pair at breakfast have at least one letter in common, no pair at lunch have a letter in common, and **all** dinner-diners have a letter in common"

Which animals ate when?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are

> Two solutions

Which are as follows

> [image]
>  [image]

Reasoning

> By definition, the intersection of the top two sets may only have one element. Since the bottom set has three elements, it follows that no animal dines for all three meals (we'll assume that each animal dines at least once).
>  That being the case, each set contains three elements and a quick check gives us that the only triplet of animals such that no pair contains a common letter is {FROG, SWAN, ELK}.
>  There are just two letters which are common to at least three animals, 'N' and 'O', which means the bottom set must contain {LION, GIBBON, FROG} or {LION, GIBBON, SWAN}. 
>  These two deductions force BEAR into the top left space. Then, LION goes into the bottom as it shares no common letter with BEAR and this also forces the position of GIBBON. ELK's position is also forced since it doesn't share a common letter with GIBBON. However, there is still a remaining ambiguity with FROG and SWAN since both share common letters with both BEAR and GIBBON.

Comment: Well done hexonimo - I stupidly made a last-minute change on some of the animal names which spoiled the uniqueness but bravo nonetheless